# How to can I specify namespace to an XAttribute while having another namespace with the same value?

Tags: c#, xml, excel, linq

All I want to do is an XML document for exporting my datatable to Excel.

So what I need is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application Excel.Sheet?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" />
```

I am using `System.Xml.Linq` and I almost have it, but my code keeps adding "ss" to the front of Workbook. This is my code:

```
    XDocument xmlssDoc2 = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), new 
    XProcessingInstruction("mso-application", "Excel.Sheet"));

    XNamespace aw = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
    XNamespace fc = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
        XElement root = new XElement(aw + "Workbook",
            new XAttribute("xmlns", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet")
        );
```

And the result I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application Excel.Sheet?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" />
```

Any Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,3e5abc19cad1911d,references) for `XElement`,  it looks as though the namespace/prefix attribute pairs are pushed onto a [push-down stack](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,84aa37da63f3d367,references) in order of addition while writing, then checked for matches against the element namespace from [top to bottom](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,151541270dad5982,references) of the stack -- effectively doing the match in reverse order in which the attributes are added.

So if you add the namespaces in the opposite order, the `ss` is omitted:

```
        XDocument xmlssDoc2 = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), new
        XProcessingInstruction("mso-application", "Excel.Sheet"));

        XNamespace blank = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
        XNamespace ss = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";

        XElement root = new XElementTest(blank + "Workbook");
        root.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ss", ss));
        root.Add(new XAttribute("xmlns", blank));

        Debug.WriteLine(root.ToString());
```

produces:

```
<Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" />
```

Of course, this means that the order of the `xmlns` attribute specifications has changed, however ideally this [should not matter](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) according to the XML specification.

Comment: Good Job! I asked the question a day before this, and actually ended up doing something similar, but your answer is spot on! Thanks dbc!