# XDocument Save Removing Node Prefixes

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document (homegrown) that has a structure like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <wf:wf version="1.0a" xmlns:wf="http://example.com/workflow" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://example.com/workflow">
  <wf:assemblies />
  <wf:dataDefinitions />
  <wf:processes />
  <wf:workflows>
    <wf:workflow id="g08615517-cdfd-4091-a053-217a965f7118">
      <wf:arguments />
      <wf:variables>
        <wf:variable id="g39ffecc9-f570-41c1-9ee0-b9358d63da3c" parameterType="Hidden">
          <wf:name>UIPTaskId</wf:name>
          <wf:dataDefinitionId>gc8f3715c-4a82-42d2-916c-51515083e7e5</wf:dataDefinitionId>
        </wf:variable>
        <wf:variable id="g46663a0c-7e60-4bd2-80df-16cd544087ad" parameterType="Hidden">
          <wf:name>UIPTaskName</wf:name>
          <wf:dataDefinitionId>g359FC555-9CC7-47D4-8ED3-EF973E7D74D7</wf:dataDefinitionId>
          <wf:value>Responsible Individual</wf:value>
        </wf:variable>
        <wf:variable id="gb32914d5-6761-4e82-b571-c8944a796fd9" parameterType="Hidden">
          <wf:name>Search?</wf:name>
          <wf:dataDefinitionId>g57201da8-62b4-46f2-9329-c71d86f39ffc</wf:dataDefinitionId>
          <wf:value>True</wf:value>
        </wf:variable>
    </wf:variables>
</wf:workflow>
</wf:workflows>
</wf:wf>
```

I have a utility to clean up the XML documents and am using XDocument to load the file and then loop through certain nodes and replace values.  Once done, I am calling the Save method to save the file in a new location and upon further inspection, the Save method is removing my wf prefix on every node.  How can I preserve this?  Am I doing something wrong?  Here is a sample of my code:

```
string wf = "wf";
string wkfl = "C:\\MyFiles\\Temp\\myfile1.rrr";

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(wkfl);
XElement variables= xdoc.Descendents(wf + "variables").Single();

foreach(XElement variable in variables.Elements(wf + "variable"))
{
    XElement name = variable.Element(wf + "name");
    name.Value = name.Value + "_MODIFIED";  
}

xdoc.Save(wkfl.Replace("\\Temp\\", "\\Modified\\"));
```

The Save method produces the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <wf version="1.0a" xmlns:wf="http://example.com/workflow" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://example.com/workflow">
      <assemblies />
      <dataDefinitions />
      <processes />
      <workflows>
        <workflow id="g08615517-cdfd-4091-a053-217a965f7118">
          <arguments />
          <variables>
            <variable id="g39ffecc9-f570-41c1-9ee0-b9358d63da3c" parameterType="Hidden">
              <name>UIPTaskId</name>
              <dataDefinitionId>gc8f3715c-4a82-42d2-916c-51515083e7e5</dataDefinitionId>
            </variable>
            <variable id="g46663a0c-7e60-4bd2-80df-16cd544087ad" parameterType="Hidden">
              <name>UIPTaskName</name>
              <dataDefinitionId>g359FC555-9CC7-47D4-8ED3-EF973E7D74D7</dataDefinitionId>
              <value>Responsible Individual</value>
            </variable>
            <variable id="gb32914d5-6761-4e82-b571-c8944a796fd9" parameterType="Hidden">
              <name>Search?</name>
              <dataDefinitionId>g57201da8-62b4-46f2-9329-c71d86f39ffc</dataDefinitionId>
              <value>True</value>
            </variable>
        </variables>
    </workflow>
    </workflows>
    </wf>
```

Comment: The code you've provided would actually give elements of `wfmain` and `wfproducts` etc as the `wf` variable is declared as a string. Could you give a short but complete example of the problem?

Comment: Actually, what I've provided above is the exact code test that I've done and the output is nearly identical.  Only variance is that instead of it being <main>, it's <wf main> (without the colon).  Everything else is the same, no prefix, just <products>

Comment: Well that's certainly not going to find any elements - you don't have any `wfmain` or `wfproducts` elements. Your loop isn't going to modify anything. Also, your original XML document should specify the namespace for the `wf` prefix - it doesn't at the moment.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wf:wf version="1.0a" xmlns:wf="http://acoeis.com/workflow" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://acoeis.com/workflow">

Comment: Does the Save method analyze the namespace declaration and if it can't reach it, ignore it?

Comment: Right, so there's more to the XML than you showed. As I keep saying, a short but *complete* example would be really helpful. I'm 99.9% sure that what you've actually got here is just defaulting - if something specifies just `xmlns=...` then that's the *default* namespace URI for that element and its descendants. So putting the `wf` prefix would actually make no difference to the meaning of the element name. I'm afraid without a short but complete example, I'm not going to be able to help you further.

Comment: I've updated the example to be as exact as I can get.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't even compile - `Descendents` should be `Descendants`. After fixing that, it then throws an exception at execution time, on the call to `Single`, because there are no elements in the sequence. I don't know why you keep ignoring my request to produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior can be reproduced simply by loading your XML and writing it again without making any edits.  Doing:

```
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        Debug.WriteLine(xdoc.ToXml());
```

Produces the output:

```
<wf version="1.0a" xmlns:wf="http://example.com/workflow" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://example.com/workflow">
  <assemblies />
  <dataDefinitions />
  <processes />
  <workflows>
      ...
```

using the helper method:

```
public static class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static string ToXml(this XDocument xDoc)
    {
        using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            xDoc.Save(writer);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

1. You have two namespaces with *identical* values, the default namespace and the namespace with prefix `wf`:

   ```
   xmlns="http://example.com/workflow"
   xmlns:wf="http://example.com/workflow"
   ```
2. Thus the prefix `wf:` means *exactly the same thing* as having no prefix at all for the `wf` element and all child elements.
3. Thus, when writing itself back to XML, `XElement` could validly use the prefix `wf:`, or use no prefix at all, without changing the semantic meaning of the output XML.
4. So how does `XElement` chose between multiple valid prefixes?  [As it turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278881/how-to-can-i-specify-namespace-to-an-xattribute-while-having-another-namespace-w/27283375#27283375), from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,3e5abc19cad1911d,references) for `XElement`, the namespace/prefix attribute pairs are pushed onto a [push-down stack](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,84aa37da63f3d367,references) in order of addition while writing, then checked for matches against the element namespace from [top to bottom](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,151541270dad5982,references) of the stack -- effectively doing the match in reverse order in which the attributes are added.
5. Thus your `XElements` are given the second of the two possible valid prefixes -- namely no prefix.

To summarize, the XML with the prefixes and the XML without the prefixes are semantically identical.  No proper XML parser should care about the difference.

Nevertheless, if for whatever reason some code you are working with assumes the `wf:` prefix rather than checking the actual namespace name (though it shouldn't), you can force your XML to be written out with that prefix by reordering the default namespace to the beginning of the root document attribute list:

```
    public static void ReorderDefaultNamespaceToBeginning(XElement xElement)
    {
        var attrArray = xElement.Attributes().ToArray();

        int defaultIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < attrArray.Length && defaultIndex == -1; i++)
        {
            var attr = attrArray[i];
            if (attr.Name == XName.Get("xmlns", string.Empty))
                defaultIndex = i;
        }

        if (defaultIndex < 0)
            return; // No default namespace

        int firstIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < attrArray.Length && firstIndex == -1; i++)
        {
            if (i == defaultIndex)
                continue;
            var attr = attrArray[i];
            if (attr.Name.NamespaceName == "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/"
                && attr.Value == attrArray[defaultIndex].Value)
                firstIndex = i;
        }

        if (defaultIndex != -1 && firstIndex != -1 && defaultIndex > firstIndex)
        {
            foreach (var attr in attrArray)
                attr.Remove();
            attrArray.Swap(defaultIndex, firstIndex);
            foreach (var attr in attrArray)
                xElement.Add(attr);
        }
    }

public static class ListHelper
{
    public static void Swap<T>(this T[] list, int i, int j)
    {
        if (i != j)
        {
            T temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[j];
            list[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

(This takes advantage of the **undocumented** fact that namespace prefixes are checked in reverse order of appearance.)  Once you do this the `wf:` prefixes will return.

Comment: Removing the `xmlns=...` attribute from the original document fixes the "problem" as well.

Comment: Jon, you and dbc were both correct.  The additional namespace declaration at the end of my xml tag was causing the problem.  Many thanks and sorry about the confusion on the example code and XML.  I'm working with highly secretive material and proprietary code and cannot copy/paste an example.