# XDocument duplicate namespace with different Local Name

Tags: c#, xml, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document that looks like this:

```
    <Schema Namespace="BBSF_Model" Alias="Self"
      p1:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false"
      xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation"
      xmlns:p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
    <EntityType Name="Customer">
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Guid" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>
  </Schema>
```

I used the below code to modify the Property Element of the document:

```
    XElement csdlEentity = csdlDoc.Root.Descendants()
            .Where(d => d.Name.LocalName == "EntityType")
            .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("Name").Value == "Customer");

    var csdlProperty = csdlEentity.Descendants()
            .Where(d => d.Name.LocalName == "Property")
            .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("Name").Value == "Id");

    XNamespace annotation = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation";
    var attrib = new XAttribute(annotation + "StoreGeneratedPattern", "Computed");
    csdlProperty.Add(attrib);
```

When I save the XDocument it the Property Element looks like:

```
    <Property Name="Id" Type="Guid" Nullable="false" p1:StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />
```

However what I want is:

```
  <Property Name="Id" Type="Guid" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" />
```

The Problem is that the xmlns "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" is referenced twice in the root node of the document with two different aliases/LocalNames (annotation, p1)

```
    xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation"
    xmlns:p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation"
```

I cannot change or tamper the root node.

How can I save the document or update the Property Element to give the required output?

Comment: You need to get the namespace from the document.  XElement schema = doc.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "schema").FirstOrDefault();

XNamespace annotation = schema.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("annotation");

Comment: @jdweng that will still get you the same namespace, so it'll give you the same result.

Comment: The reason for this is how LINQ to XML works internally.  If you swap the order of the declarations of `annotation` and `p1` then it will do what you expect.  However, either is semantically the same thing.  Arguably, you should remove `p1` as there's no reason for it to be specified twice.

Comment: Your way the namespace is not linked to the document and does nothing.  There need to be an association between the namespace and the document.

Comment: The xml we have is a CSDL file generated by Entity Framework thats why i cannot remove p1 or annotation. I am automating Visual Studio behavior in manipulating the edmx file. Tomorrow will try the suggested solutions by jdweng and dbc and i will update u. But thanks to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution all thanks to your ideas.
The general Idea is I changed the value of p1 to anything added my new attribute then returned p1 to its original value even before saving the XDocument.

```
XAttribute p1 = csdlDoc.Root.Attributes()
            .First(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration && a.Name.LocalName == "p1");

p1.Value = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation/TEMP";

......
// the same update now works as there is only one xmlns 
XNamespace annotation = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation";
var attrib = new XAttribute(annotation + "StoreGeneratedPattern", "Computed");

csdlProperty.Add(attrib);

p1.Value = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation/";
```

Another solution that worked is swapping the order or the declarations at the root node (declare p1 before annotation) like below:

```
<Schema Namespace="BBSF_Model" Alias="Self"
  p1:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false"
  xmlns:p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation"
  xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
```

In general both look like cheap solutions..

Answer (score 1):

In theory, it shouldn't matter whether you use the prefix `p1:StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed"` or `annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed"`, since these mean *exactly the same thing* -- an element with an [expanded XML name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.op_implicit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of  `{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation}StoreGeneratedPattern`.  If your receiving XML parser (or QA department?) has a problem dealing with this, the easiest fix may be to fix the parser to [conform with the standard](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).

That being said, from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,3e5abc19cad1911d,references) for `XElement`, it turns out that the namespace/prefix attribute pairs are pushed onto a [push-down stack](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,84aa37da63f3d367,references) in order of addition while writing, then checked for matches against the element namespace from [top to bottom](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,151541270dad5982,references) of the stack -- effectively doing the match in reverse order in which the attributes are added.  So if you wanted to use the prefix `annotation`, you could simply permute the order of duplicated namespaces in the root element.  (For details, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420906/xdocument-save-removing-node-prefixes/28424698#28424698).)

But, you wrote that you *cannot change or tamper the root node*.  Thus, you're going to be forced to do a bit of work: you're going to need to create your own wrapper subclass of `XmlWriter` and do the prefix remapping yourself.

First, a non-abstract subclass of `XmlWriter` that wraps a "real" `XmlWriter`:

```
public class XmlWriterProxy : XmlWriter
{
    readonly XmlWriter baseWriter;

    public XmlWriterProxy(XmlWriter baseWriter)
    {
        if (baseWriter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.baseWriter = baseWriter;
    }

    protected virtual bool IsSuspended { get { return false; } }

    public override void Close()
    {
        baseWriter.Close();
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        baseWriter.Flush();
    }

    public override string LookupPrefix(string ns)
    {
        return baseWriter.LookupPrefix(ns);
    }

    public override void WriteBase64(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteBase64(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteCData(string text)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteCData(text);
    }

    public override void WriteCharEntity(char ch)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteCharEntity(ch);
    }

    public override void WriteChars(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteChars(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteComment(string text)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteComment(text);
    }

    public override void WriteDocType(string name, string pubid, string sysid, string subset)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteDocType(name, pubid, sysid, subset);
    }

    public override void WriteEndAttribute()
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEndAttribute();
    }

    public override void WriteEndDocument()
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEndDocument();
    }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEndElement();
    }

    public override void WriteEntityRef(string name)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteEntityRef(name);
    }

    public override void WriteFullEndElement()
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteFullEndElement();
    }

    public override void WriteProcessingInstruction(string name, string text)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction(name, text);
    }

    public override void WriteRaw(string data)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteRaw(data);
    }

    public override void WriteRaw(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteRaw(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteStartAttribute(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument(bool standalone)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteStartDocument(standalone);
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument()
    {
        baseWriter.WriteStartDocument();
    }

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override WriteState WriteState
    {
        get { return baseWriter.WriteState; }
    }

    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteString(text);
    }

    public override void WriteSurrogateCharEntity(char lowChar, char highChar)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteSurrogateCharEntity(lowChar, highChar);
    }

    public override void WriteWhitespace(string ws)
    {
        if (IsSuspended)
            return;
        baseWriter.WriteWhitespace(ws);
    }
}
```

Next, subclass that allows attribute namespace prefixes to be remapped:

```
public class PrefixSelectingXmlWriterProxy : XmlWriterProxy
{
    readonly Stack<XName> elements = new Stack<XName>();
    readonly Func<string, string, string, Stack<XName>, string> attributePrefixMap;

    public PrefixSelectingXmlWriterProxy(XmlWriter baseWriter, Func<string, string, string, Stack<XName>, string> attributePrefixMap)
        : base(baseWriter)
    {
        if (attributePrefixMap == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        this.attributePrefixMap = attributePrefixMap;
    }

    public override void WriteStartAttribute(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        prefix = attributePrefixMap(prefix, localName, ns, elements);
        base.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        base.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
        elements.Push(XName.Get(localName, ns));
    }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        base.WriteEndElement();
        elements.Pop(); // Pop after base.WriteEndElement() lets the base class throw an exception on a stack error.
    }
}
```

Then finally you would use it like:

```
        string xml;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sw, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, IndentChars = "  " }))
            using (var xmlWriterProxy = new PrefixSelectingXmlWriterProxy(xmlWriter,
                (string prefix, string localName, string ns, Stack<XName> parents) =>
                {
                    if (localName == "StoreGeneratedPattern" && ns == annotation && parents.Peek() == XName.Get("Property", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm"))
                        return "annotation";
                    return prefix;
                })
                )
            {
                csdlDoc.WriteTo(xmlWriterProxy);
            }
            xml = sw.ToString();
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(xml);
```

As you can see this only remaps attribute prefixes, but it could clearly be extended to remap element prefixes by overriding [`WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cdfkth5%28v=VS.110%29.aspx).

Working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G0AqLy).