# DataContractSerializer namespace for derived class does not match specified in attribute

Tags: c#, xml, datacontractserializer

I'm expecting XML output as follows:

```
<MyBase type="MyDerived"
        xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.com/MySchema" />
```

Instead, my actual output is as follows:

```
<MyBase i:type="MyDerived"
        xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.com/MySchema"
        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

I'm using the following class definitions to attempt to generate my expected output:

MyBase.cs

```
namespace MyProject
{
    [KnownType(typeof(MyDerived))]
    [DataContract(Namespace = MyBase.Namespace)]
    public abstract class MyBase 
    {
        public const string Namespace = "http://www.mynamespace.com/MySchema";
    }
}
```

MyDerived.cs

```
namespace MyProject.Events
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = MyBase.Namespace)]
    public sealed class MyDerived : MyBase {}
}
```

And I'm using the following serialization code:

```
var knownTypes = new Type[]
{
    typeof(MyDerived)
};

var xmlDictionary = new XmlDictionary(1);
var settings = new DataContractSerializerSettings();
settings.KnownTypes = knownTypes;
settings.RootNamespace = xmlDictionary.Add(MyBase.Namespace);

serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyBase), settings);

var actual = String.Empty;

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, new MyDerived());

    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
    {
        actual = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why it's using the `XMLSchema-instance` namespace for my derived object instead of the namespace I've specified to use. I've spent over an hour digging around StackOverflow, Google, and MSDN trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I must be missing it. It seems so close, it must be a simple mistake.

Is this a problem with my class structure, or am I misapplying attributes in some way?

How can I get my expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just be misreading the XML and things are working as desired.  In your XML, the namespace `xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` is only being used to qualify the *attribute* `i:type`, and nothing else.  All of your actual data is in the namespace you specify.  If the object itself were in a different namespace, you would see something like:

```
i:type="i:MyDerived"
```

But you're not.

[`http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Instance_Document_Constructions) is a W3C globally standard namespace, knowledge of which is built in to `DataContractSerializer` (as well as many other XML serializers).  It contains 4 built-in attributes defined as follows in the [standards document](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Instance_Document_Constructions):

- `nil`: Signals that an element may be ·valid· without content if it has this attribute with the value `true`.
- `schemaLocation` and `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`: used to provide hints as to the physical location of schema documents.
- `type`:  An element information item in an instance may explicitly assert its type using the attribute `type`. The value of this attribute is a ·QName·.

The `i:type` you are seeing is the last of these standard, globally recognized attributes.  It says: "this element has the following type".  Reasons for `DataContractSerializer` to use it to represent .Net type information could include:

1. It is standard.  For instance [`XmlSerializer` recognizes and supports the same attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327.aspx).
2. Your element might have its own data attribute named `type`.  If so, it would reside in its own namespace, *not* `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`.  The latter is reserved by convention for schema information not content, thereby avoiding name collision.

For more, see [Understanding Known Types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/04/22/understanding-known-types.aspx) and [Data Contract Known Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This is basically what I suspected after research. The first example of my question is the format a third party is asking me to send. That means that `type` in their context must be part of their own namespace, thus must not be a mechanism for deserializing into a derived type with any generic serializer. I'm afraid I may have to make a custom factory that can take their `type` attribute and turn it into one of the types that I assume must be deriving a common base. That's going to be messy and hard to maintain.

Comment: @crush - if you only have to serialize and not deserialize, you could use the `PrefixSelectingXmlWriterProxy` from [XDocument duplicate namespace with different Local Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32301809/xdocument-duplicate-namespace-with-different-local-name) to remap the prefix of the `type` attribute.   Or you could [Serialize to an XDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806095/how-do-i-serialize-an-object-into-an-xdocument) and remap the attribute name with Linq to XML.

Comment: I must serialize and deserialize, unfortunately. I was looking into using a `DataContractSurrogate`, but I haven't determined if it will allow me to customize the serialization and deserialization process enough. Applying some transformations to the raw data might be a good compromise to make this work without having to write a custom factory or serializer though. I'll report back with what I come up with and add it as a supplemental answer. Your answer technically answers my question as it was asked though, so it will remain accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you'll not be able to achieve it even using custom `XmlWriter`. `DataContractSerializer` doesn't work like `XMLSerializer`. The information into your xml is added to support the fact:

> The line **xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"** tells the XML parser that this document should be validated against a schema.

Also these namespaces are considered as reserved namespaces. So if you try to override them .Net runtime will throw exception.

@dbc explained it very well and inclusion of the namespaces is part of a pretty standard process and is harmless for your xml.

If you really need to get rid of this default namespace then you just have to **hack** your XML output with string replace method. But this may lead you to problems while desalinizing.

Comment: I'm thinking that for deserializing, I can use a string replace method to add in the `i` namespace, and for serializing, I can strip it out - might be the easiest method.

Comment: Thats the only way!! I guess.