# Issue with formating of kml file with XDocument.Save

Tags: c#, xml, kml

I have a "t.kml" file something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>Test.kml</name>
    <Folder>
        <name>Test</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Placemark 1</name>
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>-150.7482419621821</longitude>
                <latitude>72.7616508182995</latitude>
                <altitude>0</altitude>
                <heading>-13.26929942603143</heading>
                <tilt>0</tilt>
                <range>33665.16192218825</range>
                <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
                <coordinates>-110.7484519621821,52.7616508182995,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

When I run this in firefox it shows like this:
[image]

I have this simple c# code which just opens and save it (though it does lot other things).

```
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string fileName = openFileDialog2.FileName;

        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName, LoadOptions.None);

        xdoc.Save("G:/Projects/t1.kml", SaveOptions.None);
    }
```

After saving it when I open this new file it is shown as:
[image]

The **issues** are:

(1) Why it is not shown in proper format?

(2) Why does it adds "kml:" as prefix before every node? How can I remove/format them?

How do I the resolve both these issue?

Edit:
By 'proper format' I mean proper xml format, the colors and other formatting as shown in first picture.

Edit 2:
How do I ensure that when it runs in a browser it shows the expand/collapse icons and colors too.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "proper format"?

Comment: The issue is that your XML has duplicate namespace prefixes for the same namespace: `xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"` and `xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"`.  And, it turns out that, when writing an `XElement`, the namespaces go on a pushdown stack so the **last** duplicate namespace controls the namespace prefix used.  That's why the `kml:` prefix gets added everywhere.  Of course either could be used and the XML would be semantically equivalent - but just look different.

Comment: This is explained in [XDocument duplicate namespace with different Local Name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32301809/3744182) -- and in fact I think this is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks  @dbc for the clarification. Is there a simple way to show/format it without adding the prefix everywhere?

Comment: Yes, eliminate the duplicated `xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"` namespace.  And remember this is just a cosmetic issue whether or not the prefix is present or absent, since the default namespace is the same as the `kml:` namespace.

Comment: @dbc - So how do I remove this from XDocument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Why it is not shown in proper format?**

That's because Firefox tries to auto-detect the filetype based on extension and data. Because your file doesn't end with `.xml` and `XDocument.Save` adds a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the output file, the file is not shown as XML.

So you could save your file without BOM by using a `XmlTextWriter` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48622702/1300910)) or rename your file to `.xml` if you just want to view it occasionally with Firefox.

**2. Why does it adds "kml:" as prefix before every node? How can I remove/format them?**

That's because you have a duplicate namespace for `kml` and `XDocument.Save` applies the last matching namespace to each node as mentioned by dbc in the comments. Also, this is just a cosmetic issue you shouldn't have to worry about.

However you can workaround this by removing the `xmlns:kml` namespace declaration before saving it:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName, LoadOptions.None);
foreach (var attr in doc.Root.Attributes())
    if (attr.IsNamespaceDeclaration && attr.Name.LocalName == "kml")
        attr.Remove();
doc.Save(@"G:\Projects\t1.kml", SaveOptions.None);
```

*Outputs*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <Document>
    <name>Test.kml</name>
    <Folder>
      <name>Test</name>
      <open>1</open>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Placemark 1</name>
        <LookAt>
          <longitude>-150.7482419621821</longitude>
          <latitude>72.7616508182995</latitude>
          <altitude>0</altitude>
          <heading>-13.26929942603143</heading>
          <tilt>0</tilt>
          <range>33665.16192218825</range>
          <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <Point>
          <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
          <coordinates>-110.7484519621821,52.7616508182995,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 1):

One part of your question (about "kml" prefix) has already been answered, so I'll answer only another one (about display in firefox). The reason it doesn't display as xml tree in firefox (or chrome) is when saving `XDocument` with utf-8 declaration - UTF8 with BOM (byte order mark) is used. BOM is 3 special bytes at the beginning of the file, giving a hint that file is encoded in UTF-8. Those bytes confuse firefox for some reason, and it treats the file as plaintext.

So to fix this issue, you need to save your document in UTF-8 without BOM, for example like this:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName, LoadOptions.None);
using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(outputFile, new UTF8Encoding(false))) {
    xdoc.Save(writer);
}
```