# .Net Add namespace to XML document as default and with a prefix

Tags: .net, vb.net, xml-namespaces, xmlserializer

When using XMLSerializer to create an XML string of a serialization of a class  oXML in vb.net as follows:

```
Dim x As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(oXML.GetType, "urn:oecd:blah:blah")
Dim xmlns = New XmlSerializerNamespaces()

xmlns.Add(String.Empty, "urn:oecd:blah:blah")
xmlns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
xmlns.Add("sfa", "urn:oecd:blah:blah1")
xmlns.Add("iso", "urn:oecd:blah:blah2")
xmlns.Add("ftc", "urn:oecd:blah:blah")

Dim sw As New IO.StringWriter()
x.Serialize(sw, oXML, xmlns)
```

You will notice that I have repeated the addition of namespace "urn:oecd:blah:blah" as both an empty "default" namespace on the xmlns object and also in the definition of x As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.

The problem is that this particular namespace only ever gets rendered with a prefix of ftc and the default is not shown. If I comment out the addition of the ftc namespace, and run it again, then a default namespace is rendered correctly. Is there a way to tell the serializer that this namespace is used as default and also with a prefix of ftc? I am assuming it is because the namespace is used twice, both as default and also with a prefix that it is ignoring it?

Comment: I'm not sure it's worth the effort of trying to force this to happen - it shouldn't make any difference, from an information point of view. Remember that prefixes only have local meaning within the XML document.

Comment: Added to which, how could the `Serialize` method possibly make *use* of having multiple prefixes registered - all it knows is that it has elements or attributes to write and which namespace they belong to - how would this method, hypothetically, work out which elements should use the `ftc` prefix and which elements should not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` has no defined behavior in the case of passing an `XmlSerializerNamespaces` with two prefixes for identical namespaces.  It could choose either prefix and the result would be semantically identical.  Further, from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializerNamespaces.cs) for the class it appears the namespaces are stored in a hash table so their order is unpredictable.  But since the XML would have the same meaning either way, the simplest thing for you to do is to not worry about it.

If for some reason you *must* have duplicated namespaces in your XML, and *must* use the default prefix in preference to an equivalent named prefix for elements in that namespace, you could serialize to an `XDocument` then add the missing duplicates manually:

```
Public Module XObjectExtensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> 
    Public Function SerializeToXDocument(Of T)(obj As T, serializer As XmlSerializer, ns As XmlSerializerNamespaces) As XDocument
        Dim doc = New XDocument()
        Using writer = doc.CreateWriter()
            serializer = If(serializer, New XmlSerializer(obj.GetType()))
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, ns)
        End Using
        If doc.Root IsNot Nothing AndAlso ns IsNot Nothing Then
            ' Add missing namespaces
            For Each name In ns.ToArray().Except(doc.Root.Attributes().Where(Function(a) a.IsNamespaceDeclaration).Select((Function(a) New XmlQualifiedName(a.Name.LocalName, a.Value))))
                doc.Root.Add(New XAttribute("xmlns" + (If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(name.Name), String.Empty, ":" + name.Name)), name.Namespace))
            Next
        End If

        Return doc
    End Function
End Module
```

And then use it like:

```
        Dim xDoc = oXML.SerializeToXDocument(x, xmlns)

        Dim xml2 as String
        Using sw = New IO.StringWriter()
            xDoc.Save(sw)
            xml2 = sw.ToString()
        End Using
```

Example [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hydCwG).

Now, in your case the default namespace was omitted in favor of a duplicated prefixed namespace.  If for some reason `XmlSerializer` chose to do the opposite (and it's not documented which it will choose), then adding the missing named namespace at the end of the root document's namespace list would cause all elements to be written with the named prefix.  That's because it turns out that, when writing an `XElement`, [name/namespace pairs are pushed onto a stack during serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278881/how-to-can-i-specify-namespace-to-an-xattribute-while-having-another-namespace-w/27283375#27283375) and so the lattermost is used.  To work around this, you could adapt the code from [XDocument Save Removing Node Prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420906/xdocument-save-removing-node-prefixes/28424698#28424698) and move the default prefix to the *end* of the attribute list rather than the *beginning*.