# Use of XmlSerializerNamespaces

Tags: xml, xmlserializer

When I use :

XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("ftc", "urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1");

the result is the xml:

**xmlns:ftc="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1"**

but i need this result (both namespaces):

**xmlns="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1" xmlns:ftc="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1"**

Is it posible?
Sorry my english is bad.

Comment: An namespace is a URL and a prefix.  You can have only one prefix on a tag.  You can have multiple namespaces defined for each node (element and descendants).  But only one namespace can be used at any one time from the list of defined namespaces.

Comment: See [.Net Add namespace to XML document as default and with a prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158470/net-add-namespace-to-xml-document-as-default-and-with-a-prefix).  Is that a duplicate, or are you using a different language (c#)?