# XML Namespaces Order XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008, xml-namespaces

Below are the namespaces added to create the XML

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();                        
            ns.Add("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            ns.Add("versione", "FPA12");
            ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

Desired Output

```
<FatturaElettronica xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versione="FPA12" xmlns="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2">
```

Generated Output

```
<FatturaElettronica xmlns:versione="FPA12" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2">
```

Is there a way to change the Order of the namespaces and also in the Generated output you can see **xmlns:versione="FPA12"** but the client wants only
**versione="FPA12"**

Comment: Being curious, how does the order of attributes matter for an xml element?

Comment: Yeah true. but the client wants it to be in the same order even after explaining it doesn't matter

Comment: If you just want `versione="FPA12"` that would be a normal attribute, *not* a namespace declaration, so you wouldn't add it via `XmlSerializerNamespaces`.

Comment: ok I will make that change. Can you pls help me with the other requirement

Comment: I have never come across an XML serializer that gives you control over the order of namespace declarations. You aren't supposed to care. You seem to be in the classic position of having a client who doesn't understand what they are asking for.

Comment: Chances are that, if they *really* do need the text in that order, you're going to continue to encounter further issues - they're apparently not using XML tools themselves, they're manually manipulating strings. It's unlikely that XML tools will fit their rigid custom code.

Comment: Seems similar to [.Net Add namespace to XML document as default and with a prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158470).  In that question also control of the namespace order was required (even hough it shouldn't matter).  Same hack/workaround may work here also.

Comment: I've come across a scenario where it does matter: version control. Nothing to do with XML semantics, but it's annoying to see file diffs come up for no good reason just because object `GetHashCode` is pulling the strings.